# Contains of a String

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

There's a status in my table that says `Up,Paused,Stopped`.

If All selected have Up: console.log("all up");

If All selected are Up OR Paused: console.log("all up or paused");

If All selected are Stopped: console.log("all stopped");

Else: console.log("do nothing");

How do I make sure ALL have this condition? This code doesn't work because it will say up multiple times instead of comparing them all.

```
 $('#dataTable tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    var rowsStatus = table.row('.selected').data()[2];
    $.each(rowsStatus, function (index, rowStatus) {
        if(rowStatus.indexOf("Up") > -1) {
            console.log("up")
        }
    });
} );
```

Comment: We would need to see your HTML in order to help you

Comment: Why? The status is here: `table.row('.selected').data()[2]` this is pure javascript

Comment: It's text. like `<td><span class="label label-success fa fa-arrow-up"> Up 38 hours</span></td>`

Comment: None of your conditions will ever be true, because your status is `"Up,Paused,Stopped"`, so don't worry about it

Comment: I'm asking because there are much better ways of doing this than using `data()` with an index, and looping through your entire `tbody`, but it depends on how your HTML is structured.

Comment: table.row('.selected').data()[2] says the status with a string Stopped, Up or Paused

Comment: The missing information is you have a DATATABLE: https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data() - I added the tag for you

Comment: Just create a counter for each value. Loop and check and increment the correct counter. after the loop, use your logic to check the counters and output the value you want. Then you can delete the question and we can move on with our lives (i.e. waste more of our lives on SO)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you need. Here I have just used an `array` as there is no html included, its unable to test. Hope it works fine.

```js
var arr = ["Up","Paused","Up","Stopped","Stopped","Up"];
var isallup = true, isallpaused = false, isallstopped = true, isanythingstopped = false;
$.each(arr, function (index, rowStatus) {
    if(rowStatus.indexOf("Up") > -1 ) {
        isallstopped = isallpaused = false;
    }
    if(rowStatus.indexOf("Paused") > -1 ) {
        isallstopped = isallup = false;
    }
    if(rowStatus.indexOf("Stopped") > -1 ) {
        isanythingstopped = true;
        isallpaused = isallup = false;
    }
});

console.log("Is all Up : "+isallup);
console.log("Is all Up or Paused : "+!isanythingstopped);
console.log("Is all stopped : "+isallstopped);
if(isanythingstopped && !isallpaused && !isallstopped)
{
    console.log("do nothing");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```